# get NSString from NSFetchRequest issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I'm using Core Data and I need to loop thru the result of the request, create several custom objects in the loop and store them in a NSMUtableArray, so I can send it to another view to feed a UI component. This is what I'm doing:

```
    NSMutableArray *persons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                                   entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {

        ToggleButtonInfo *btn = [[ToggleButtonInfo alloc] init];

        NSString *personName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ww %@", [info valueForKey:@"name"]];
        NSLog(@"pn: %@", personName);
        [btn setButtonInfo:personName];

        [persons addObject:btn];
    }        
    [fetchRequest release];

    return persons;
```

The loop is working just fine, the information is there. The problem is that I get a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" in my component if I use:

```
[info valueForKey:@"name"]
```

if I do something like this:

```
[btn setButtonInfo:@"something else here"];
```

everything works fine. So it looks like **info** is been de-allocated and that is causing the error, right? I try creating the scring using **stringWithFormat** but it doesn't work, same error.

An ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS? I assume it's later when you're displaying the button? `-setButtonInfo:` probably isn't retaining, or you're over-releasing somewhere else.

Note that you're leaking `btn` in this code.

Comment: yes, I get the error later where I display the button. Question: why leaking? isn't it owned by the NSMutableArray? won't it be released when the NSMutable array is de-allocated?

Comment: You have a retain on it from when you called +alloc. NSMutableArray has a retain on it from when you called -addObject:. When you deallocate the array, the array will release the object, but your +alloc retain will still be on it, and it will leak.

Comment: You should also update the question with the stack trace and code from where it actually crashes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about the leak Rob. What would be the best way to release the objects that I'm adding to the NSMutableArray?

Comment: There is no stack trace, just this: Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Comment: You're running in Debug mode, and the Debugger doesn't pop up with a stack?

Comment: found the error, you were right, I wasn't retaining the values in the object, I was just using settles and gettles. I get the stack for all other errors but this one, weird.  Tks!

Comment: how should I release the objects? If I release them after I add them to the NSMutableArray i get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Which objects? You should release any object you create using one of the three magic words (http://robnapier.net/blog/three-magic-words-6). You should not release any other objects.

Comment: how and when should I release the "btn" objects I'm creating in the loop. Yes, they are leaks. If I do "release" after adding them to the NSMutableArray, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. What is the correct way to do it? thanksfor your help.

Comment: You should release them immediately after calling addObject:. If that's crashing, you have an error elsewhere, and should look at the stack to see what's actually failing.